# remove field name in linq select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC 5 C#.

I have a list object. This is the Class Object:

```
public class CameraDevice
{
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string UDN { get; set; }
    public string DocumentURL { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsUSB { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }        
}
```

A list is created with this object type:

```
var devices = new List<CameraDevice>();
```

I want to populate a dropdown with just 1 of the fields from this list object.

So:

```
public ActionResult Connection()
{
    var model = new ConnectionData();
    model.Devices = new SelectList(devices.Select(i => new { i.FriendlyName }), "Device");
    return View(model);
}
```

My viewmodel class is:

```
public class ConnectionData
{
    [Display(Name = "Device")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select")]
    public string SelectedDevice { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> devices { get; set; }
}
```

My html5 markup is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDevice, Model.Devices, "Select Device", new { @style = "width: 355px;height:21px; border:none;outline:0px;" });
```

The problem is the field name is included in the dropdown:

[image: Sample Data]

How can I remove the field name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the property name which should be used as Value and Text for the DropDownList.

Use SelectList contructor this way:

```
model.Devices = new SelectList(devices
                               .Select(i => new { i.FriendlyName }),
                               "FriendlyName",
                               "FriendlyName");
```

The second parameter is DropDownList value field which will be posted to action on form submit and second is display text field for dropdown list, as you are selecting one property so i have passed `FriendlyName` property to both.

or if you want to use SelectList constructor which takes one parameter, in that case don't create anonymous type while projecting as you are selecting just one property, so just do this way:

```
model.Devices = new SelectList(devices
                               .Select(i => i.FriendlyName));
```

Comment: Hi, this is all new to me but now makes sense. Thank you

Comment: This makes me laugh as I always forget how SelectList works even when I have done it a lot of times. So the solution is paste it in a Sticky notes. Just a friendly reminder.

Comment: @Aizen well said...;)